# A sequence of closed non-self-intersecting curves on the unit sphere

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I’m considering a way to construct a nontrivial infinite series of closed curves ${T_i}$ on the 2-dimensional unit sphere in $R^3$ which has these properties:

- $T_0$ is a closed smooth curve on the unit sphere having no self-intersection,
- $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}, T_{i+1}= dT_{i} /ds_i$  where the derivation variable is the arc length parameter of $T_{i}$,
- $\forall i \in \mathbb {N}$, $T_i$ has no self intersection

After drawing a few of these curves I realized there quickly appears a self intersecting curve at some point.

Also, it is known that the geodesic curvatures $\kappa_{i}$ and $\kappa_{i-1}$ of two consecutive terms $T_{i}$ and $T_{i-1}$ satisfy the following relationship:

$$ \displaystyle \kappa_{i} = \frac{\frac{\text{d}\kappa_{i-1}}{\text{d}s}}{(\sqrt{1+\kappa_{i-1}^2})^3}$$. (from V. I. Arnold, Geometry of spherical curves, p.27).

Besides, it’s also known that $\forall i \in \mathbb \{1,2,3,...\}, \int _{0}^{L_i}{\kappa_{i}ds_i= 0}$ where $L_i$ is the length of $T_{i}$ for the reason that these curves are successive tangent indicatrices of spherical curves.

Some of the questions I’m concerned about are these:

1. Which conditions must $T_0$ satisfy in order to have an infinite series of non-self-intersecting curves?
2. Under which conditions does this series converge?

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for improving the question after it had been closed! – It might be instructive to given an example of curves $T_0, T_1, \ldots$ which eventually self-intersect.

Comment: Certainly a circle would suffice; great circles in particular are fixed points of this recurrence relation, up to a reparameterization. It might be worthwhile to see what happens to the recurrence relation when applying a small perturbation to a great circle, and see if this fixed point has any kind of stability.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for your comment. In order to draw the curves I wrote a little program which computes numerically the values of the coordinates for the subsequent derivatives. For example, for $T_0$ having an equation: $r(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t), \sin(t)* \cos(t))/(1+\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t))$, T_3 has a self intersection. As Kajelad also pointed out in his comment, circles on the unit sphere are a trivial case where the sequence become stationary (since the tangent indicatrix of a spherical circle is the great circle parallel to it).

Comment: @Kajelad yes, you’re correct about the great circles. I will look further into this approach, thank you!

Comment: Actually how would one categorize that kind of recurrence formula again? Is there a name for it?